# Dictionary/Collection of generic Delegates

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have want to have a collection of generic delegates, each tied to a different string key (something like a `Dictionary<string, delegate<T>>`). The delegates take in `T` and return `T`, meaning that the return type is the same as the input type, kind of like functional `map`. This means the type for each individual function is known at compile time. I see no reason why this shouldn't be possible but I haven't found a way to do it.

The main solutions I've seen are to make `T` an `object` and then cast it each time, but that's a hassle. Another option is to use dynamic, but that undermines type safety and might bring problems in the long run. There's also the possibility to implement a custom collection, but I'm not sure as to how.

Edit: I want a generic key-value pair where `T` is a different type for each key/pair.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Can you please post sample code of how you envision this collection being used? (for multiple types `T`).

Comment: Sure, I want  function that takes in a value and returns a modified version, lets say `delegate T Modifier<T>(T obj)`. I want to store these in a collection with string as the key. For each individual key, I want `T` to be a different value. For example, if the key is `"name"` then `T` should be `string`, but if the key is `age` then it should be `int`. Then I want to be able do something like `age = dict["age"].invoke(age)`. which should return `int`.

Comment: Do all the elements in your map share the same delegate-type, which is `Func<T, T>` apparentyl?

Comment: Seems like you want `Func<T, T>`-instances in your collection. SO finally you have a `Dictionary<string, Func<T, T>>`.

Comment: Yes, all elements are `Func<T, T>`. I understand what you mean that the dictionary basically collapses `T` to a certain type, but then what I want to know whether it's possible to have a collection behave like this?

Comment: Func<T, T> will still require T to be the same for each element. The OP wants to be able to have T different for each element. of the dictionary.

Comment: @Dobby1235 Thank you for adding code sample as a comment. How about modifying your question to include your sample code instead?

Comment: @ThorynHawley is this so? OP didn't answer if `T` is the same for all elements or not.

Comment: They did in a comment: " For each individual key, I want T to be a different value."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the post with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the details of storage and provide your own methods to set and get the delegates in a custom class:

```
public class DelegateDictionary 
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _entries = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Add<T>(string key, Func<T, T> modifier)
    {
        _entries.Add(key, modifier);            
    }

    public Func<T, T> Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return _entries[key] as Func<T, T>;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dictionary = new DelegateDictionary();

dictionary.Add<string>("NameLowerCase", (name) => name.ToLower());
dictionary.Add<int>("AgeIncreaseByFive", (value) => value + 5);

var lowerCasedName = dictionary.Get<string>("NameLowerCase").Invoke("JUAN");
var numberIncreasedByFive = dictionary.Get<int>("AgeIncreaseByFive").Invoke(5);

Console.WriteLine($"JUAN => {lowerCasedName}");
Console.WriteLine($"5 => {numberIncreasedByFive}");
```

Output:

```
JUAN => juan
5 => 10
```

This is an overly simplified example but it should be enough to get you going.

All this being said, when I see something like this, it's usually a code smell worth taking a step back and rethinking why you need this in the first place.

Comment: "All this being said, when I see something like this, it's usually a code smell worth taking a step back and rethinking why you need this in the first place." -- Totally agree

Comment: This solution requires the caller to know the return type of the value in advance of calling Get. At that point, you may as well be be using a switch. 
That said, this is a great way to partially obfuscate the delegates.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like the best solution. I still feel like it should be possible though, It shouldn't be any different from using just using generic functions. Invoke should return `T`, which is defined by the parameter.

Comment: @Dobby1235 the thing is that you still need to know the type so you can invoke it. This is why to me, this is a code smell.

Comment: @Dobby1235 You could make an Invoke function `public void Invoke<T>(string key, T value) => Get<T>(key).Invoke(value);` then you can just do `dict.Invoke(someKey, someValue);` and not need to supply the type parameter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible. The whole point of generics is that when T is used in a context it is the same type for the whole of that context. By using T as part of the value type for the dictionary, you are linking all of the values into the same context, and thus a single type for T.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: The answer is that it is not possible given the provided restrictions. That answers the question.

Comment: It that case, is it possible to have a (key - value) collection where each key has it's own generic context or `T`? It doesn't have to be a dictionary, I just used it as an example.

Comment: The problem isnt the dictionary. its that you want it in a collection. Collections require that all objects have the same type, or some super generic type (like object). You might be able to achieve this with something untyped like an arraylist, but that isnt key/value.

Comment: Perhaps we could help more if you elaborated on what you are trying to accomplish with your string -> delegate relationship?

Comment: The string only serves as a key. The collection stores 'Modifiers' that modify a certain value in several way. I want it very generic by design. For example, there might be a key `"ToGerman"`, which takes a string and translates it to German. But there might also be a key that takes an `int` and changes it according to some external factor. The intention behind it is a card game, where a card's properties can be modified in a non-destructive, written (meaning that we can look in to the collection and see the modifiers), and removable way.

Comment: As long as you are willing to accept that you will need to know the return type in advance of calling Get<T>, then JuanR's answer will work for you.